# My asyncio server test hang forever sometimes

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-asyncio, python-3.6

### My Async Server Test code hang forever sometimes..

1. I made asyncio server and I wanted to test my async server about sending request and receiving response
2. But I didn't know how to unittest my async server.. So I search in google and finally I found that Asyncio unit test announced at 2019 Pycon

   - link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQ6rpLRJsXs
3. And I found another unit test code about asyncio server using code in number 2

   - link: https://agariinc.medium.com/advanced-strategies-for-testing-async-code-in-python-6196a032d8d7
4. So I wrote my async server test code referring to the code in number 3

   ```py
   class AsyncServerResponseTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()

        self.runner = LoopRunner(self.loop)
        self.runner.start()

        self.server = AsyncServer(self.loop)
        self.runner.run_coroutine(self.server.start_server())

        self.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.client.connect((HOST, PORT))

    def tearDown(self) -> None:
        self.runner.stop()
        self.runner.join()

    def _send_request(self, command, data=""):
        send(self.client, command, data=data)
        return recv(self.client)

    def test_response_command_should_equal_COMMAND1_on_request_some_request1(self):
        # Given: Request Command is some_request1.
        request_command = "some_request1"

        # When: Send request to Async Server and Receive response.
        response_header, response_body = self._send_request(request_command)

        # Then: Response Header's command is COMMAND1
        self.assertEqual(response_header.command, COMMAND1)
        # And: Response body is equal to BODY1
        self.assertEqual(response_body, BODY1)

    def test_response_command_should_equal_COMMAND2_on_request_some_request2(self):
        # Given: Request Command is some_request2
        request_command = "some_request2"

        # When: Send request to Async Server and Receive response.
        response_header, response_body = self._send_request(request_command, request_body)

        # Then: Response Header's command is COMMAND2
        self.assertEqual(response_header.command, COMMAND2)
        # And: Response body is equal to BODY2
        self.assertEqual(response_body, BODY2)

    def test_response_command_should_COMMAND3_on_request_some_request3(self):
        # Given: Request Command is some_request3
        request_command = "some_request3"

        # When: Send request to Async Server and Receive response.
        response_header, response_body = self._send_request(request_command)

        # Then: Response Header's command is COMMAND3
        self.assertEqual(response_header.command, COMMAND3)
        # And: Response body is equal to BODY3
        self.assertEqual(response_body, BODY3)
   ```
5. When I Wrote first unit test, It runs It worked well
6. But I wrote second and third unittest, It hangs forever sometimes..
7. It works well when running one unit test each.
8. but, when running together, it sometimes hang forever or sometimes worked well. I don't know why.. :(
9. I upload `LoopRunner` and `AsyncServer` class togather.
10. Thank you for reading my question.

##### LoopRunner class

```py
"""
    This code is almost same with code that I linked in number 3
"""
class LoopRunner(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, loop):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, name="loop_runner", daemon=True)
        self.loop: asyncio.BaseEventLoop = loop

    def run(self):
        asyncio.set_event_loop(self.loop)
        try:
            self.loop.run_forever()
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            self.loop.close()
        finally:
            if self.loop.is_running():
                self.loop.close()

    def run_coroutine(self, coroutine):
        result = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(coroutine, self.loop)
        return result.result()

    def _stop(self):
        self.loop.stop()

    def run_in_thread(self, callback, *args):
        return self.loop.call_soon_threadsafe(callback, *args)

    def stop(self):
        return self.run_in_thread(self._stop)
```

##### AsyncServer class

```py
class AsyncServer:
    def __init__(self, loop: asyncio.BaseEventLoop) -> None:
        self.reader: asyncio.StreamReader = None
        self.writer: asyncio.StreamWriter = None
        self.loop = loop

        self.response_queue = asyncio.Queue(loop=self.loop)

    async def start_server(self) -> None:
        server_coroutine = asyncio.start_server(
            self.__client_connected, host=HOST, port=PORT, loop=self.loop, **{"reuse_port": True}
        )

        await server_coroutine

    async def __client_connected(self, reader: asyncio.StreamReader, writer: asyncio.StreamWriter):
        self.reader = reader
        self.writer = writer

        await self.__create_tasks()

    async def __create_tasks(self) -> None:
        self.loop.create_task(self.__handle_response())
        self.loop.create_task(self.__handle_request())

    async def __handle_response(self) -> None:
        while self.loop.is_running():
            response_command, data = await self.response_queue.get()
            await send_response_packet(self.writer, response_command, data)

    async def __handle_request(self) -> None:
        while self.loop.is_running():
            header, body = await receive_request_packet(self.reader)

            response_command, response_data = self.__make_response(header.command, body)
            if not response_command:
                continue
            await self.response_queue.put((response_command, response_data))

    def __make_response(self, command, body) -> Tuple[Header, str]:
        if command == "some_request1"
            # Action to suit request1
            response_command, response_data = command1, response_body1
        elif command == "some_request2"
            # Action to suit request2
            response_command, response_data = command2, response_body2
        elif command == "some_request3"
            # Action to suit request3
            response_command, response_data = command3, response_body3
        else:
            return

        return response_command, response_data
```

※ My python version is 3.6 So I can't use `asyncio.run()`, `async with ..` etc... sorry.. :(

#### Thank U again for reading the long scratch.